# Table Row becomes wider when clicking on button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a strange problem with my prototype for a webcalendar in HTML.

I am using bootstrap4 and created a table with "time-buttons" which can be selected by the user.

Everytime when i click on a random time-button, the tables with more than 3 "time-buttons" (when there is a overflow) become wider. I dont want that effect.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gdwujum4/

Can someone explain why that happens? Did i miss something?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>test.html</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
      <style>
    
    
      .topcorner{
        top: 0px;
        right: 4px;
        /* position: absolute; */
        cursor:pointer;
      }
      .list-group{
         height: 100px;
         /* max-width: 90%; */
         overflow-y: auto;
      }
    
    
      td {
    
        background-color: lightgrey;
        height : 130px;
        max-width: 130px;
      }
    
      button  {
        min-height: 33% ;
        max-height: 33% ;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    
    
      }
    
      </style>
      <script type= "application/javascript">
    
      $(document).ready(function(){
    
        $( ".topcorner" ).on( "click", function ( e ) {
          e.metaKey = true;
    
          $(this).toggleClass("ui-selected");
          $(this).parent().css( "background-color", "red" );
    
          $( "button.list-group-item" ).each(function( index ) {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
    
          });
    
    
        } );
    
    
    
        //$( "li" ).on( "click", function ( e ) {
        //funktioniert auch mit zukünftigen elementen
        $(document).on("click","button.list-group-item",function(e){
          e.metaKey = true;
    
          $(this).toggleClass("active");
    
          $( ".topcorner.ui-selected" ).each(function( index ) {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-selected");
    
          });
    
        } );
    
    }); </script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container-fluid mx-0 px-0 mx-md-auto px-md-auto" style="max-width:911px">
      <table class="table table-bordered" >
    
    
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="1" class="text-center">&larr;</th>
          <th colspan="5" class="text-center">Februar 2018</th>
          <th colspan="1" class="text-center">&rarr;</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Mo</th>
            <th class="text-center">Di</th>
            <th class="text-center">Mi</th>
            <th class="text-center">Do</th>
            <th class="text-center">Fr</th>
            <th class="text-center">Sa</th>
            <th class="text-center">So</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    
          <!-- Woche 1-->
          <tr>
    
            <td class="position-relative"></td>
            <td class="position-relative"></td>
            <td class="position-relative"></td>
            <td class="position-relative"></td>
            <td class="position-relative"></td>
            <td class="position-relative"></td>
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">1</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
    
          </tr>
    
          <!-- Woche 2-->
          <tr>
    
            <!--                       !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!                   -->
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">2</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">17:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">19:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">3</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">18:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">20:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
    
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">4</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">5</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">6</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
    
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">7</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">8</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
          </tr>
    
          <!-- Woche 3-->
          <tr>
    
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">9</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">10</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
    
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">11</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">12</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">13</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
    
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">14</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">15</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
          </tr>
    
          <!-- Woche 4-->
          <tr>
    
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">16</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">17</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
    
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">18</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">19</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">20</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
    
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">21</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">22</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
    
    
          </tr>
    
          <!-- Woche 5-->
          <tr>
    
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">23</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">24</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
    
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">25</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">26</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">27</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
    
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">28</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">29</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
    
          </tr>
    
          <!-- Woche 6-->
          <tr>
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">30</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
    
            <td class="position-relative px-2 py-0">
              <div class="position-absolute topcorner">31</div>
    
              <div class="list-group text-center mt-4 mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled>12:59</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pt-0 pb-0 pr-0 pl-0">15:00</button>
              </div>
            </td>
    
            <td class="position-relative"></td>
            <td class="position-relative"></td>
            <td class="position-relative"></td>
            <td class="position-relative"></td>
            <td class="position-relative"></td>
    
    
    
          </tr>
    
    
    
    
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the Bootstrap outline...

https://jsfiddle.net/t0cnfp9k/2/

```
button.list-group-item.active,
button.list-group-item:focus{
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: Short, fast and precise answer. thanks, you saved me a lot of time and nerves.